# Use of stock image on book cover

Tags: publishing, legal, artwork, book-cover

My book was published by a now defunct publisher.  They returned my records to me (locked, and I could not open any of the documents) and I've since re-published my title under my own name.  However, my question is ... can I still use the same cover?  The image on my cover is appropriate for the material, but I assume it was a stock image the initial publisher paid a "right to use" fee for.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: That is a difficult question to answer without knowing the details of the license issued for the use of the image.  I think it would be best to contact the copyright holder for information and advice.

Comment: You might be able to find out who the copyright holder for the picture is by using Google Images' reverse image search.  Go to google images at https://images.google.com and click the camera icon.  Then upload the image in question.  Google will search the web for similar images  and in the process probably locate one or more instances of your exact image.  One of the links associated with one of those exact matches may lead you to the owner of the image.

Comment: I would go with a new cover. You don't have the rights to the artwork. You will need a new ISBN and other changes to show that you are the publisher now. Give your book a fresh start!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely commission or make a new cover. 
If you are going to self-pub on Amazon, simply use THEIR cover-maker, a link to it will come up when you go through the publishing process.

Comment: I wouldn't use Amazon's cover creator since it's not professionally designed, but yes I'd agree with a new cover image for sure!